# How to find whether a sting have "UKV-IVAKVDT4" this pattern

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a random string. So if a string contains this "UKV-IVAKVDT4" it returns true or false. How do i write regex for find this pattern. In "UKV-IVAKVDT4" the first three character may change for every user. What i want is i just find whether a string contains this pattern or not?

Comment: we could do with more details to what the pattern is. so far we have 3 letters folowed by a dash. are numbers accepted? is this uppercase only? the second part of the string, what are the parameters for that?

Comment: try `INPUT.match(/U\w\w\-IVAKVDT4/)`

Comment: yes all should be in upper case only

Comment: I mean I need to check first 3 characters are alphanumeric after that allow hyphen after that 8 characters alphanumeric.  "UKV-IVAKVDT4" this is not a static. It may change for every user.

Answer (score 2):

based on your comment, this should do the trick: `([A-Z0-9]{3})-([A-Z0-9]{8})`

Comment: "UKV-IVAKVDT4" this is not a static one. It should change for all users. So i just check whether a sting a have this pattern "first 3 characters are alphanumeric after that allow hyphen after that 8 characters alphanumeric"

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

`/[A-Z]{3}-[A-Z0-9]{8}/`

For javascript it would be:

`text.match(/[A-Z]{3}-[A-Z0-9]{8}/)`

Comment: How to use this in php preg_match

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't use PHP but if you are programing this on php you should change the tags on this question

Comment: <?php
$match = array();
$subject = "sdfsd UKV-IVAKVDT4 fsdfsdfsdfsdf";
preg_match("/[A-Z]{3}-[A-Z0-9]{8}/", $subject, $match);
print_r($match[0]);
?>

Comment: I have changed in php

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function TestString(stringToTest)
{
    return stringToTest.match("[A-Z]{3}-IVAKVDT4")!=null ? true: false;
}
```

For building regular expressions go through this article.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-Minute-Regex-Tutorial

**[EDIT]**
  Answer for your question. "How to use it in Php"

```
<?php
   $str = "The user ticket id is UKV-IVAKVDT4.Use this for future use";
   $match=  array();
   if(preg_match("/[A-Z]{3}-IVAKVDT4/", $str,$match)) 
    { 
        print_r(array_values($match));
    } else 
    {
        print 'No Match found';
    }
?>
```

Comment: How to use this in php preg_match

Comment: if (preg_match("[A-Z]{3}-IVAKVDT4", $stringToTest)) { //do something} else {//do some other thing}

Comment: could you please tell me how to extract a pattern matched string from whole string. Like i have a sting like "The user ticket id is UKV-IVAKVDT4.Use this for future use" . So i need to get "UKV-IVAKVDT4" from the string

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to the following regEx

```
var matched = false;
var testRegEx = /^([A-Za-z0-9]{3})[\-]{1}([A-Za-z0-9]{8})$/i;
matched = testRegEx.test("your input string")
```

Comment: "/^([A-Za-z0-9]{3})[\-]{1}([A-Za-z0-9]{8})$/i" what is the meaning of i in regex

Comment: For PHP preg_match you can use in same way by placing this as the pattern to match. Please check the [PHP Doc here once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)